# Postgres SQL requires me to wrap my insert with brackets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple order table that holds ordered data for a shopping app.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."order"
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    order_type character varying(12)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    first_name character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(64)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    guest boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    location integer,
    user_id integer,
    phone character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

Initially, I had a JSONB column but was having trouble inserting data

My current query ideally would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO public."order"(
    order_type, first_name, last_name, phone, email, guest, location, user_id)
    VALUES ('Something', 'Answer', 'hello', '1234567890', 'some@email.com', true, 123, 0) RETURNING *;
```

But it is causing an error with the following:

> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Something" LINE 3:  VALUES
> ('Something', 'Answer', 'hello', '1234567890',...

> DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. SQL state: 22P02 Character: 114

But if I wrap those values inside a "{}", it inserts fine.

Why is that? I have other table that don't need the values to be wrapped in brackets so there is something I am not understanding and need help with that.

```
INSERT INTO public."order"(
    order_type, first_name, last_name, phone, email, guest, location, user_id)
    VALUES ('{Something}', '{Answer}', '{hello}', '{1234567890}', '{some@email.com}', true, 123, 0) RETURNING *;
```

> Successfully run. Total query runtime: 158 msec. 1 rows affected.

Comment: `character varying(12)[]` - is the usage of an array intentional, or is this a typo?

Comment: In your table ddl you use arrays, so your insert requires arrays as well.

Comment: @NicoHaase works fine for me. I could change it to text[]. I was just looking for MYSQL "varchar" with character limits and that was the closest thing.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I did! Then I drop and recreated it and it's still doing this. Does this mean that it requires all my insert value to be wrap with a bracket?

Comment: Why do you need to use an array for this? Anything not working when omiting the brackets?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's a MYSQL habit. It works fine on other tables though. Here is one for a user name `first_name character varying(24)[]` I am transitioning into Postgresql from Mysql so there is some features I want to explore and JSONB was one of them. JSONB was in this table before I removed it to see if things would work without its complication.

Comment: [] is for arrays and you most likely don’t need them. When you’re new to PostgreSQL, don’t start with arrays

Comment: @FrankHeikens I think that was the issue! I didn't notice having [] after the data type would require it to be an array. Mind blown! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."order"
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    order_type character varying(12)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    first_name character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(64)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    guest boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    location integer,
    user_id integer,
    phone character varying(24)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

When creating the table

```
first_name character varying(24)[]
```

Having the "[]" by the data type would require to be an array

Thus

```
first_name character varying(24)
```

would no longer need the value to be wrap in brackets